# CQRS: write to RDBMS, read from NoSQL?

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, cqrs

I've been thinking on separation the read and write flows and even make them use different databases to provide best fast data availability by horizontally scaling the "read" databases. I'm gonna make my project write into a database, push objects change notifications into a queue so another service read messages and copies updated data to one or more denormalized "read" databases. Thinking on this I've found that this would be bad if the "write" database is denormalized too.
Example: say there is a user profile with a name of university user has graduated. Say I store this information in the "write" database like this:

```
{ userId: 100, name: "John", universityId: 200, universityName: "Cambridge"}
```

Say user opened his profile for editing and while he was doing it another person, the Cambridge representative, has changed name from "Cambridge" to "C.U." and saved changes so they gone to both "write" and "read" databases. Service which updated university name finished its work and "thinks" now university is OK everywhere. After this moment the first user saves updated profile with old university name and this name will go to every place his profile presents.
This kind of issues make me think that "write" database **must** always be normalized, not contain duplicates. But I never met this principle from what is written about the CQRS. Am I thinking wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got it right!

This "principle" is written very clear and detailed in the [DDD book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) by Eric Evans. The rule is that **Aggregates can reference other Aggregates only by their ID**. In CQRS, Aggregates are used/accessed only on the write side.

On the other hand, the read models should be optimized for reading and denormalization is one way to do this. I always do it. They can be kept in sync by listening to the right events.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by: "They can be kept in sync by listening to the right events."? +1.

Comment: @w0051977 the write models emmit events. The readmodels listen to some events that are interesting/relevant to them and uptate their internal state. By "right" I meant "relevant".

Comment: Thanks, but what happens if the read model responds to the event but fails to write to the read database (NoSQL) e.g. because it is offline.  Wouldn't the two databases (SQL and NoSQL) be out of sync?

Comment: @w0051977 Not necessarily. It depends on the architecture. If the readmodel runs in the same process as the write model then that's exactly what happens. You can however put the readmodel on a microservice/separate-process and tail the eventstore. Which one you choose it depends on your resilience needs.

Comment: In order to create an event store; must my entire app be built with Event Sourcing in mind? Also should I be using a tool like this: https://eventstore.org/ or do you create your own event store? Last question.

Comment: @w0051977 no, it must not all be eventsourced. I did use my own ES, it's your choice...

Comment: Sorry, are you saying: 1) it must not be event sourced or 2) It can be event sourced but this is not necessary.  Thanks again.

Comment: @w0051977 2). By "Must not" I mean that it is not required

Comment: If you would like to answer my question here from last week then please do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50235881/onpost-events-run-before-a-commit.  I am trying to find a simple example of an Event Store.  I would be grateful for an answer in the context of an event store.

Comment: @w0051977 but the context is not the Event store so I cannot give an answer to an imaginary question. Regarding that question: I don't use a service bus because of those problems; tailing an Event store is a simpler and safer method.

Comment: Can I ask if your message queue is stored in SQL Server (SQL Server Broker Services) or MSMQ? I was thinking about using SQL Server Broker services.  Then I can have one process that adds a record to sql server and adds a message to broker services (as one atomic unit) - then a second process that processes the Broker Services queue adding records to the NoSQL database.  I promise this is the last question.

Comment: @w0051977 I don't use any kind of queue. The single source of events is the source of truth, the Event store, that is built on MongoDB. When a new Readmodel is built, I read all the relevant events then I tail the `rs log`.