# OnPost events run before a commit

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Say I have some standard NHibernate code like this, which writes to an SQL database:

```
using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
  using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
  {
      var customer = session.Get<Customer>(id);
      customer.Property1 = "new value";
      customer.Property2 = "new value";
      tx.Commit();
  }
}
```

I am trying to create a copy table for the Customer (in a NoSQL database).  Therefore when the code above runs the following event handler runs:

```
public void OnPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent postUpdateEvent)
        {
            if (postDeleteEvent.Entity.GetType() == typeof(Customer)) 
            {
                var customer = (Customer)postUpdateEvent.Entity;
                customerCopyRepository.Update(customer);
            }
        }
```

If I was to change the first code fragment to an insert, then this would run:

```
 public void OnPostInsert(PostInsertEvent postInsertEvent)
        {
            if (postInsertEvent.Entity.GetType() == typeof(Customer))  
            {
                var customer = (Customer)postInsertEvent.Entity;
                customerCopyRepository.Insert(customer);
            }
        }
```

and when a delete occurs this runs:

```
public void OnPostDelete(PostDeleteEvent postDeleteEvent)
        {
            if (postDeleteEvent.Entity.GetType() == typeof(Customer)) 
            {
                var customer = (Customer)postDeleteEvent.Entity;
                customerCopyRepository.Delete(customer.Id);
            }
        }
```

CustomerCopyRepository is injected into the class constructor.

This is working very nicely.  The only problem I have is that each of the events above seem to run before the data is committed to the database.  Therefore the following scenario could occur:

1) Write Customer to NoSQL database.

2) Customer is not written to SQL database(because of an SQL error).

Is there any way I can prevent this scenario?

Comment: This seems like a scenario for a service bus.  or some sort of domain events to fire like OnSaved that then is picked up and moved to the NoSql repo with retries and an error queue if the update fails on the NoSql side.

Comment: @Fran, why do the events in my post exist if you cannot use them Post i.e. PostUpdate, PostDelete etc? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not saying you can't use them, I'm just saying using a full fledged ESB with retries and an error queue and eventual consistency is a better solution for the reasons are having with the events.  Right now, any failure is going to leave you system in an inconsistent state and you don't have a message that either completed or errored out.  So how does your system recover?

Comment: I'm using EventListeners, but as a replacement for triggers in my db to update audit fields on a given entity at PreInsert or PreUpdate.

Comment: @Fran, what happens if your database insertion/update does not run after the PreInsert/PreUpdate runs? Thanks again.

Comment: They all run in the same transaction so they get rolled back.

Comment: @Fran, of course they do.  You only have one database to worry about.  Do you know any concrete examples, which show how to integrate NoSQL and NHibernate?

Comment: Yes, I worked in a system that used an ESB to keep a nosql reporting schema in sync with our sql server based system.

Comment: @Fran, was it open source? I guess you are talking about something like this?

Comment: No, it was a commercial app.  it ran on NServiceBus.

Comment: @Fran, I did not post the link at the end of my last comment.  I meant to include this: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR.  Is NServiceBus similar to Mediatr? Thanks.

Comment: I have passing famialiarity with Mediatr.  I saw of it more of a UI piece that with everything handled in process.  Full ESB's provide a lot more.  I found this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40759503/is-mediatr-a-good-fit-for-updating-multiple-mongodb-read-models) that mirrors what I am saying.

Comment: @Fran, I have setup a simple NServiceBus app to see if it meets my requirements.  Does NServiceBus guarantee that errors are always written to the error queue? How does it do this? If you write an answer then I will give some credit.  Thanks.

Comment: It should.  You can use a transactional queue.  On a separate note, think olabout the separation of commands and events.  From your example I saw a save command that then would broadcast an customersaved event.  Which then would get picked up and send an command  to save the customer update to the external system.

Comment: @Fra, how can it guarantee to write to the message queue? What happens if the user closes the web browser or the server crashes or runs out of hard disk capacity? (this is the last question).

Comment: so for all the particulars i'd point you to the [docs](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/operations/transactions-message-processing).  but say for closing a web browser, if your web client is only writing to a local queue, that should almost be guaranteed to success once you are on the bus you are good.  Does the UI care that you wrote to an external system or just that he customer got saved locally?  it's really how you design your system.  you could have multiple independent end points a single endpoint,...

Comment: This [book](https://www.amazon.com/Learning-NServiceBus-Second-David-Boike/dp/1784392928/ref=sr_1_1) was a good resource when I started using nservicebus

Comment: Thanks, I will check out that book at the weekend.  Where are Service Point 'All Failed Messages' stored? I have three failed messages, however they do not appear in any of my queues.

Comment: See here https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/recoverability/configure-error-handling

Comment: My error queue has no messages in it (since I installed Service Pulse).  In fact none of my queues have messages in them.  Service Pulse appears to be intercepting them and storing them somewhere else (Service Pulse tells me I have two error messages).  I may have to ask another question on here.

Comment: @Fran, I have asked another follow on question here if you would like to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288894/does-service-pulse-use-the-defined-error-queue.  It is a follow on from my last comment.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same scenario (Sync with ElasticSearch) and I ended up by using the RegisterSynchronization method:

```
private void Sync(IPostDatabaseOperationEventArgs e)
{
    e.Session.Transaction.RegisterSynchronization(new AfterTransactionCompletes(success =>
    {
        if (!success)
            return;

        // Do your stuff
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  What happens if the code under "do your stuff" fails? Can you rollback the transaction?

Comment: No, this method is called after the transaction is completed. We thought about this point too but since our SQL database is the single source of truth we decided to live with this gap. Also I think it would be very complicated to ensure all transactions to all data stores are completed and to have a fallback for everything.

Comment: How do you compensate for a failure? Do you retry at a later time?